# i have a triangle and i need to count a + b + c

Tags: c

How do i write this line correctly?

```
if(a + b + c = 180)
```

This is my code. I need to do a + b + c in the `if`-statement:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int A;
    int B;
    int C;
    int triagolnik = 180;

    scanf("%d %d %d", &A, &B, &C);

    if (A + B + C = triagolnik)
        printf("DA\n");

    if (A, B, C = 80)  // I want to make a + b + c = 80 but i don't know the right line
        printf("PRAVOAGOLEN");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `=` assigns, `==` compares.

Comment: SO is not a replacement for reading the first chapters of a C programming book.

Comment: You mean to write `if (A+B+C == triagolnik)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other people suggested you should be using `==` to compare, `=` is used to assign values to variables. As it seems to me, `A`, `B` and `C` are angles and the first check that you do is that you check if it is the case of valid triangle. If that's the case simply apply the suggested modification:

```
if (A + B + C == triagolnik)
    printf("DA\n");
```

In the second check, thanks to the same language, I seem to understand that you want to check whether the triangle is `right` one. If that's the case I don't see why you are mentioning the number 80, as the correct one should be 90. The correct check for `right` triangle would be:

```
if (A + B + C == triagolnik && (A == 90 || B == 90 || C == 90))
    printf("PRAVOAGOLEN\n");
```

Comment: Thank you i did my exercise

Comment: I put 80 by a mistake

Comment: Fala ti se ucam sega c pocnav pa poleka poleka :D